# on search suggest click content go to the text area in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

When I type some keyword in `input` the search option appears, but when I click on the suggested keyword it will not go to the address of that search result. How can I make search results contain links to the results?
A working sample is on http://max2colors.com/ website on the search option.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajaxSearch()
{   
    var input_data = $('#query').val();

    if (input_data.length === 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    }
    else
    {

        var post_data = {
            'query': input_data,
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
            };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/autocomplete",
            data: post_data,
            success: function (data) {
                // return success
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            }
         });

     }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the input value based from the clicked suggestion item, try using jquery code like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#autoSuggestionsList li').click(function (e) { // suggestion item click event
    $('#query').val($(this).text()).focus(); // get the suggestion value & apply the value to the input
    $('#suggestions').hide(); // close the suggestion list
});

function ajaxSearch()
{   
    var input_data = $('#query').val();

    if (input_data.length === 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions').hide();
    }
    else
    {

        var post_data = {
            'query': input_data,
            '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
            };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/autocomplete",
            data: post_data,
            success: function (data) {
                // return success
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $('#suggestions').show();
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                    $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: its not working i am trying multiples time please any one suggest

Comment: Where do you put the code? could you read the errors (if any) on the console?

Comment: if (input_data.length === 0)
    {
       // here is paste your code
    }

Comment: no, put it outside the function. for example before or after the `function ajaxSearch(){}`

Comment: Hi @Ram, I've updated the code just so you know where to put the codes

Comment: hiee.. @hasta its work for me you can check on https://www.max2colors.com/ on search option but i have one more question,i want o impliment on search list keyboard up and down scroll option,  please help me, i know you can do that. by d way mannyyyyyyyy thanks to you.